# Incorrect variable values in recursive Jekyll includes

Tags: recursion, jekyll, liquid

This is a bit of a complicated issue to explain fully so I'll just give the problematic details. I am using a whole bunch of includes to generate sections of content in a page based on variables defined in the front matter. It all worked fine until I tried to include a content section within another content section. From within the first content section I call the "selector" include that decides which include to use based on the "type" of the content. This seems to correctly see the values of the variable that is passed in. When the "selector" then calls the include for the type of the sub-content, that include seems to recieve that values of the outer content. It makes no sense to me! Am I missing something stupid or is this a bug?

the "selector":

```
resource!
{{ include.resource.type }}
{{ include.resource.title }}
{{ include.resource.term }}
{%- assign type = include.resource.type -%}
{%- if type == "document" %}{% include collection/type/document resource=include.resource -%}
{%- elsif type == "term" %}{% include collection/type/term resource=include.resource -%}
{%- elsif type == "youtube" %}{% include collection/type/youtube resource=include.resource -%}
{%- elsif type == "custom" %}{% include collection/type/custom resource=include.resource -%}
{%- else %}{% include error text="resource type not found" %}{% endif -%}
```

the inner content's include:

```
{%- assign resource = include.resource -%}

term:
{{ resource.type }}
{{ resource.title }}
{{ resource.term }}

{%- capture content -%}
{%- assign term = site.glossary | where: "name", resource.term | first -%}
{% unless term %}{% include error text="term not found" %}{% endunless %}
{{- term.content -}}
{%- endcapture -%}
{%- include collection/type/default title=resource.title content=content -%}
```

Instead of the expected:

```
resource! term What is Git? gitterm: term What is Git? git
```

I get:

```
resource! term What is Git? gitterm: youtube Video!!!
```

The second half is what I would expect from the parent content...

The relevant includes ("selector"=resource, content type include=type/term) can be found [here](https://github.com/CFRCR/CFRCR/tree/master/_includes/collection). The page that I'm testing on can be found and [here](http://cfrcr.cyberdro.me/collections/intro_to_git/) (live, source in the repo at CFRCR/_collection/intro_to_git.md).

Comment: Update: seems to be an issue with the {%- assign resource = include.resource -%} in the inner content's include. Replacing all instances of resource with include.resource makes it work as expected. Looks like assigns carry over from super-includes and can't be reassigned... Liquid docs don't even say that you can use things other than strings or booleans (https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/tags/variable-tags#assign)...

Comment: Think we stumbled across the same issue. https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/7080#issuecomment-397672949